# Can I create a Dictionary from sorted IEnumerable without resorting?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, optimization

In C#, let's say that I have an `IEnumerable<Tuple<int, string>>`
It is sorted by it's int element. I want to do O(log n) lookups from it, and sure I can do it like this, using System.Linq:

```
var lookups = alreadySorted.ToDictionary(x => x.Item1, x => x.Item2);
foreach(var i in someArray) someMethod(lookups.Find(i));
```

But that has one shortcoming: It has to sort again the already sorted `IEnumerable` when making the `Dictionary` because it can't know I have already sorted it. Is there any reasonable way work around that?

EDIT: I've been told Dictionary is not for traditional binary search, but for hashmapping, so this example should be using System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet instead

Comment: Maybe if you make you lookups field of type SortedList you can avoid re-sorting.

Comment: `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` uses hashing to achieve close to `O(1)` lookups - but in doing so they're definitely *not* order preserving.

Comment: And a bare `IEnumerable<anything>` doesn't offer random access, so you can't implement a binary search atop it (which is probably what you were thinking of when you said `O(log n)`).

Comment: SortedList? Never heard of such, I thought there is SortedSet resembilng a sorted list. But I don't know how I can make a Set out of IEnumerable without it resorting it in process.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I realize I have to copy it to a new memory block to allow random-access. But I want to do it without resorting in progress.

Comment: @dukc - but the point is, `Dictionary` *doesn't* sort items anyway - it hashes them and uses the hashes for access. So the enumerable being "pre-sorted" is of *no* benefit since the items aren't in the correct order for the `Dictionary` anyway.

Comment: Ahh it's hashmap, not a traditional set? Good to know. Still, if I want a traditional set without resorting (I assume SortedSet is for that), how?

Comment: I think it's even faster to `Join()` the `IEnumerable` with `someArray`, because also for making a dictionary or a list, the sequence has to be iterated once.

Comment: @GertArnold Yeah in this case, but if I want to reuse lookups later I'd still go with making it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to obtain `O(log n)` lookups and to avoid any further sorting, you should use `ToList()` rather than `ToDictionary()`.

You would then use [`BinarySearch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftfdbfx6(v=vs.110).aspx) with a custom `IComparer` that only compares on `Item1` of the `Tuple`.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. Can I anyhow convert it to SortedSet without resorting? Not required but could be helpful.

Comment: Why are you so concerned about re-sorting @dukc ?

Comment: It wastes computing power. Ok, I confess I'm not making anything so performance-critical I couldn't afford that but faster is always better.

Comment: Faster isn't *always* better, sometimes readability and maintainability are more important.  In fact, I'd go so far as to say that unless performance is actually causing an issue, it comes 3rd in that list.

Answer (score 0):

As a continuation to the answer of Damien_The_Unbeliever, I defined the following method inside an utility class, so I don't have to make new classes for the IComparer:

```
   public static Tuple<int, int> IndexesOf<Et, Ct>(this IList<Et> haystack, Ct needle, Func<Et, Ct, int> func)
    {
        int minStart = 0;
        int maxStart = haystack.Count();
        int minEnd = 0;
        int maxEnd = haystack.Count();
        while(minStart != maxStart)
        {
            int i = (minStart + maxStart) / 2;
            var direction = func(haystack[i], needle);
            if (direction < 0)
            {
                minStart = i+1;
                minEnd = i+1 < minEnd? minEnd: i+1;
            }
            else if (direction == 0)
            {
                maxStart = i;
                minEnd = i+1 < minEnd ? minEnd : i + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                maxStart = i;
                maxEnd = i;
            }
        }

        while (minEnd != maxEnd)
        {
            int i = (minEnd + maxEnd) / 2;
            var direction = func(haystack[i], needle);
            if (direction <= 0) minEnd = i+1;
            else maxEnd = i;
        }

        return Tuple.Create(minStart, minEnd);
    }
```

which is then used like

```
foreach(var i in someArray)
{   someMethod(lookups[lookups.IndexesOf(i, (a, b) => a.Item1 - b).Item1]);
}
```

Of course it's somewhat wasteful to look for index range of all matches instead of just index of one match.